# JAVA connection to server via thread

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, sockets, server

I can't solve this problem: how can I send and receive strings from a server without making the GUI Start button disabled until the end of the interaction? (Maybe I also need to make it so that the button can be pressed multiple times to request many strings) I know I have to use threads but I don't know how.

I hope I explained myself

This is the listener added to the Start button

```
public class startListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Thread t = new Thread();
        System.out.println(t);
        try {
            t.start(); //I put this randomly, I don't know how to use it
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(Main.socket.getOutputStream());
            write.println("start");
            write.flush();
            
            Scanner read = new Scanner(Main.socket.getInputStream());
            String s = read.nextLine();
            String tot ="";
            //while (read.hasNextLine()) { 
            for(int i=0; i<24;i++) {
                System.out.println("I read: " + s);
                tot += s + "\n\n";
                s=read.nextLine();
            }
            Main.Log.append(tot);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Regardless to your question, currently your Thread doesnt do anything. In order to create a new Thread, you have to implement the runnable() or extends the thread() class. If you want it to run without  creating an extra class, you would go like so: `new Thread(new Runnable(){//your code goes here}).start()`